# Weighted Average notation - Adjusting weights in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, definition

I'm trying to calculate the weighted average of a statistic sample (vector) in **R** using this form:

[image: form]

The function takes a vector and the weight is adjusted according by a second parameter (1 - 3), which are:

[image: weights]

where `s` is the standard deviation.

I've adjusted the weight accordingly if the parameter is 1 or 3 using `else-if`'s, but I'm having trouble with the 2nd one given that there is criteria to meet...

I've been calculating `X - xBar` as a vector: `m = x-mean(x)`

I've been calculating `s` with an **R** function: `s = sd(x)`

My query is regarding how "the meeting of the conditions should be programmed" in the 2nd critera. So far I have an `if` for each condition, but...

When calculating the weighted average, (taking the top one as an eg), does each element of the `x` vector (`m/s`) need to be less than 1? or do I need to test each element and assign a weight from the 3 conditions accordingly?

eg. if the first elements answer was less than 1, assign a weight or 1, but second elements answer was inbetween 1 and 2, assign it a weight of 0.5?

I hope this makes sense. In **R** it throws a warning message saying the logic is only comparing the first element of the vector... so thats what raised the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the warning message while staying reasonably efficient, you probably want to use `ifelse` rather than `if` and `else`, perhaps in something like

```
m <- mean(x)
s <- sd(x)
absstandardx <- abs( (x - m) / s )
w2 <- ifelse( absstandardx < 1, 1, ifelse( absstandardx < 2, 0.5, 0 ) ) 
weightedmean2 <- sum(w2 * x) / sum(w2)
```

Comment: Ah, cool implementation of `ifelse`. I always forget that function. Excellent answer. Thanks for posting. Just for clarification, each element is tested here and assigned either a `1, 0.5, 0` weight? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes.  Take a small test set such as `x <- c(0,1,25,3,16,5,2,4)`  and see what you get for `absstandardx` and `w2`

Comment: Yeh, I just did. Works great. Was just checking I was seeing things correct. Thanks again for posting.